# Flutter: theming with ThemeData.light for most colors, but ThemeData.black for buttons?

Tags: flutter

I am playing with the theme settings in Flutter, and with the basic light theme in my ThemeData, I am getting purple colors everywhere eg with buttons. How can I change that? I wanted to set the button color background to black, and tried

```
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.black,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: In that case it should be better to use copyWith()  and pass the buttons themes directly